# Next step after ANOVA

Tags: anova, post-hoc

The ANOVA test I ran on my dataset resulted in the rejection of the null.

What is the way to tell which treatment is significantly different from the others?
Should I do a bunch of paired t-tests or eliminate one treatment a time and run the ANOVA again on a subset of the data?

Comment: The possible outcomes might surprise you: for instance, it's possible for *none* of the treatments to differ significantly from any of the others (or even from the controls). It might be best to turn the question back to you for clarification: precisely what hypotheses are meaningful in your application and require such *post hoc* ANOVA testing?

Comment: Thanks! Here’s a kind of question that I have in mind: suppose there are several diets, and I want to find out which of them is best for losing weight. Wouldn’t the starting point in answering this question be to run a one-way ANOVA to determine whether a diet matters for weight loss at all?

Comment: That's right.  And if your ANOVA says there is a detectable difference among the diets, wouldn't the best conclusion be that it's the diet that produced the greatest weight loss in your dataset?  The point is that you might not need any additional test at all in this circumstance.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @whuber there is one additional thing you should check: is the difference of the best diet to the second (or the control group) "significant" not in the statistical, but in the colloquial meaning: is it large enough to be of practical value.

Answer (score 3):

Here a quick graphical view of the
challenges one may encounter in a balanced
one-way ANOVA. its analysis, and (if the null hypothesis is rejected) *post hoc*
comparisons.

Consider the following fictitious
data with five levels of the factor and 20
replications of each.

```
set.seed(2922)
x1 = rnorm(20, 10, 3)
x2 = rnorm(20, 15, 3)
x3 = rnorm(20, 17, 3)
x4 = rnorm(20, 20, 3)
x5 = rnorm(20, 22, 3)
```

The "truth" (from the method of simulation) is that all five level population means differ,
but boxplots give a preview that sample means
may not show the true pattern of the population means.

```
x = c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
g = as.factor(rep(1:5, 20))
boxplot(x~g, horizontal=T, notch=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

The notches in the sides of the boxes are
calibrated for comparing two groups (levels) at a time:
roughly speaking, if notches overlap, then
there may be no significant difference in level locations.

The null hypothesis that all five group population means are the same is overwhelmingly rejected
with a P-value near $0.$

```
anova(lm(x~g))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: x
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
g          4 2025.36  506.34  49.238 < 2.2e-16
Residuals 95  976.94   10.28
```

If you wish, you can make formal
*post hoc* comparisons using Tukey's HSD (or
another favorite method), but there is clearly no hope we will find evidence in the data that $\mu_1 < \mu_2 < \mu_3 < \mu_4 < \mu_5.$

---

*Note:* As on [this page](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/08/how-to-perform-tukey-hsd-test-in-r/),
here is a one-way ANOVA with *ad hoc* Tukey HSD comparisons:

```
aov(formula = x ~ g)
Call:
   aov(formula = x ~ g)

Terms:
                        g Residuals
Sum of Squares  2025.3599  976.9356
Deg. of Freedom         4        95

Residual standard error: 3.206795
Estimated effects may be unbalanced

TukeyHSD(aov(x~g))

Tukey multiple comparisons of means
   95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = x ~ g)

$g
          diff       lwr       upr     p adj
2-1  7.2635232  4.443511 10.083536 0.0000000
3-1  6.8540855  4.034073  9.674098 0.0000000
4-1 11.2652881  8.445276 14.085301 0.0000000
5-1 13.0256273 10.205615 15.845640 0.0000000
3-2 -0.4094377 -3.229450  2.410575 0.9943178
4-2  4.0017649  1.181753  6.821777 0.0014038
5-2  5.7621040  2.942092  8.582116 0.0000014
4-3  4.4112026  1.591190  7.231215 0.0003250
5-3  6.1715418  3.351529  8.991554 0.0000002
5-4  1.7603391 -1.059673  4.580352 0.4172278
```

Comment: Thanks so much!